jetzt erstmal frohe Weihnachten
The sentence is said at the end of the following podcast: https://slowgerman.com/2024/12/24/typisch-deutsch-typically-german/
Does it really mean "now for the first time Merry Christmas" (which is odd in English) or does "jetzt erstmal" have another meaning in this context? DeepL translates it as "for now".

Well, DeepL is right.

"Erstmal" is rather a colloquial particle, not so much a temporal adverb. A temporal adverbial with the meaning "for the first time" would rather be "zum ersten mal" or at least "erstmals" – so that would be a statement about the time or order of the events you are talking about. But note that "schöne Weihnachten" in isolation, like here, is a greeting or a wish, not a statement. That fits in with a particle use of "erstmal". The meaning of particles is rather at the level of subjective attitude or has to do with the function that your utterance is meant to have.
The sentence can mean "that's the first thing that should be said", or "now and first of all let's have a beautiful Christmas, other things can be postponed".

Another common example would be after a day of hard work: "Jetzt erstmal was essen", Jetzt erstmal 'n kühles Bier", "Jetzt erstmal nach Hause".

"That's the first thing that should be said" doesn't make sense in this context because the sentence is said at the end of the podcast, not at the beginning.

@AlanEvangelista, in this case it can mean something like, now everyone have a merry Christmas before we meet again for the podcast. One would need a bit more context.
